# Stacked interleaved horizontal barchart in Pandas / matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm a bit of a python rookie, but i'm trying to create a horizontal stacked bar chart that shows the order and duration of the activities.

The data is stored in pandas in the following format.

```
   Team Name        | Duration |  Activity      | Activity Colour
0  Party Planners 1 |  3.0     |  Cake          | #7E07F7
1  Party Planners 1 |  4.0     |  Balloon       | #EBB975
2  Party Planners 1 |  2.0     |  Cake          | #7E07F7
3  Party Planners 1 |  1.0     |  Entertainment | #214B22
4  Party Planners 1 |  5.0     |  Balloon       | #EBB975
5  Party Planners 2 |  1.0     |  Cake          | #7E07F7
6  Party Planners 2 |  3.0     |  Logistics     | #27943A
```

Ideally, there should be two series, Party Planners 1 and Party Planners 2 with the order of activities respected and the colour corresponding to that in the dataframe. Excuse the paint, but something like this:

[image]

Anyone know if this is possible in this datastructure format? Possibly I need to revisit how the data is formulated if matplotlib is not a fan.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `groupby` to create each planner horizontal bar (I'm using `reverse(tuple(...))` here so
that the expected presentation order is preserved). You can then use [matplotlib.pyplot.barh](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.barh.html#matplotlib-pyplot-barh) to display each
activity over the grouped horizontal line. Applying the parameter `left` as a scalar value in the `barh`, with the sum of all previous plotted activities for that group you can achieve the desired output.

> Each of y, width, height, and `left` may either be a scalar applying to all bars, or it may be a sequence of length N providing a separate value for each bar.

> Parameters: `left` : sequence of scalars. The x coordinates of the left sides of the bars (default: 0).

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
print(df)

for name, group in reversed(tuple(df.groupby("Team Name"))):
    leftsum = 0
    for idx, row in group.iterrows():
        plt.barh(row["Team Name"], row["Duration"], left=leftsum,
                label=df.loc[idx, "Activity"],
                color=df.loc[idx, "Activity Colour"])
        leftsum = sum(group.loc[:idx, "Duration"])

# remove duplicate labels
handles, labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
by_label = dict(zip(labels, handles))
plt.legend(by_label.values(), by_label.keys())

plt.xlabel('Duration')
plt.show()
```

[image: party-planners vs duration]

Comment: Worked like a charm! I'll refer back to your comment to bisect some of the wizardry that went on here. Given me a lot to investigate. Thank you!